# problem with AUCTEX

Tags: emacs

Hi I have been using EMACS -Auctex for doing my work in LATEx. Today when I tried to compile my document as usual with C-c and C-c the latex code does not compile saying there are errors. I tried pressing C-c ` the usual keys to see the errors but all i get is a blank screen. The latex code compiled perfectly when I was working with it 1.2 an hour ago.

I am freaking out since I have homework due today and my editor is bailing on me :(

Any suggestions? I tried to compile with KILE bu I can't understand the errors

Comment: You can still try to do it on the console by invoking LaTeX from there (`latex mydocument.tex`).

Comment: Press `C-c C-l` to see the compilation output in another window (then `C-x o` to switch to that other window). Beyond that, what you have is probably a (La)TeX error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the intermediate files created in producing a pdf/dvi/ps file get corrupted. You can clear them out with C-c C-c clean. After issuing the clean, try to recompile again and you might get sensible results.